# calling a variable from one function to another function in c#

Tags: c#

i need to call the string "final" in the function emp2. when i try it says "final does not exist". Both the functions are in different class files.

```
internal class emp
{
    internal void empl(int id, string name, string sal)
    {
        empdet test = new empdet(id, name, sal);
        string final = test.ToString();
    }
}

public class empdetls
{
    public static void emp2( XElement element)
    {
        XElement element = XElement.Parse(final);

        // ...
    }
}
```

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Need to see xml. and empdet method.

Comment: You are running into a [scope](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973875.aspx) issue.

Comment: It's impossible to tell you how to overcome this without knowing two things. First, who (i.e. which class) calls the `emp2` method? Second, are you free to change the method signature of `emp2`?

Comment: i have updated the code now. hope this helps

Comment: I've reformatted your code. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

You should use private field.

```
public class emp
{
       private String final;
        internal void empl(int id, string name, string sal)
        {

           empdet test = new empdet(id, name, sal);
           final = test.ToString();
        }

        public static void emp2( XElement element)
        {

           XElement element = XElement.Parse(final);
           .....
           .....
        }  
}
```

Comment: This is incorrect for two reasons. First, it appears from the original code that the `empl` and `emp2` methods are in different classes. Second, even if they were within the same class, your code will not compile because you are trying to access the non-static variable `final` from the static method `emp2`.

Comment: How should i overcome this

Answer (score 0):

Just pass in a parameter to your `static` method. `static` methods should be free of particular instances, anyways.

```
public static void emp2(XElement element, string final)
{
    // ...
}
```